# showing Vue is not defined error while importing vue-router

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I have created a new project using vue-cli '`vue init webpack-simple my-app`' command. In that fresh installation copy, I'm trying to import vue-router in the App.vue component that was created by default. But it is giving me an error: '`Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined`'. If I import the vue again in App.vue, then the app is working fine. But I already imported the vue in main.js, so why do I need to import it again in App.js? Is there any way I can use the imported vue from main.js? Here is my code:

main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Vue from 'vue';   //**why I need to import it again? I already imported it in main.js
  import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
  Vue.use(VueRouter);

  import QuestionOne from './components/QuestionOneTemplate';

  const routes = [
    { path: '/', name: 'QuestionOne', component: QuestionOne },
  ];

  const router = new VueRouter({
    routes
  });

  window.router = router;

  export default {
    router,
    name: 'app',
    data () {
      return {
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style lang="scss">
</style>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way i can use the imported vue from main.js?

No, you need to import it in every file that uses `Vue`. The imports/requires are how things get hooked up. Rest assured, each import will be the same singleton instance.

You can get to the router from a Vue component's javascript using `this.$router` and `this.$route` without an import, or inside a template, using simply `$router` and `$route`

Not recommended, but you **can** assign Vue to a global in main.js, and use the global without importing.

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
global.MyVue = Vue
```

App.vue

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

MyVue.use(VueRouter);
```

## Why

This is how ES6 links things up.  Consider it `wiring`.  If there were more than 1 Vue lib available, how would the linker know which to use?  What if another library defined a variable or function called Vue?  Perhaps a lib uses its own internal Vue for an event bus or other feature.

## Other Thoughts

The explicit import also makes IDE autocompletion and syntax highlighting work better.  Some IDEs can add the imports automatically, and that makes life easier.

Comment: how can i assign Vue globally?

Comment: @AlauddinAhmed I added example to answer.

Comment: what MyVue.install(Foo) is for?

Comment: Use MyVue instead of Vue without importing.  Its just and example of installing a plugin called Foo.

Comment: @AlauddinAhmed Why are you not installing the router in main.js?  That is the conventional place to do it? Your new Vue(...) is supposed to contain the router..

Comment: now its showing 'Uncaught ReferenceError: MyVue is not defined' .
maybe i wasn't thinking it in right way.  Ok let me install the router in main.js. maybe that will solve all those issue.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Applying route to main.js avoided the issue

Answer (score 1):

did you try this ?

`import Vue from 'vue'
 import VueRouter from 'vue-router'`

then use

`Vue.use(VueRouter)`

because the error message means you need to import vue first to use vue-router

Comment: yes.. i did exactly the same. But the question is, i already imported Vue once in main.js . why i need to import it again in App.js ?

Comment: you just call vue in your main because of instantiation of your project. you need to install manually per component / .vue

so the solution is to put your router globally not in per component

Answer (score 0):

You did the right thing and you don't have to worry about importing Vue in multiple files. When you are shipping your application and build it for production, you will have only one "Vue import". If you take a look at dist folder and your bundled `.js` files you will notice that Vue is imported only once.

Comment: what about in development environment? currently i'm working on it.

Comment: @AlauddinAhmed you do not have to import multiple times during both development and production. There will be a npm script to build your projects and the import will be done globally.

Comment: @RuChernChong but right now, without importing it again, its giving me an error.

Comment: Did you run `npm run dev` at all?

Comment: @RuChernChong yes

Comment: Actually, as the accepted answer indicates you have to import Vue where ever you use it.  The bundled `.js` file only has one import because there is only one file.  In the development environment, your code is spread amongst many files.  Each one that needs to use `Vue` needs to import it.  Webpack will remove the redundant imports.